# How can I send multi response data using Netty?

Tags: netty, httpresponse

I want to return multiple response data to a client on a server using Netty(4.1.51).
According to our specifications, the first response data is in the format of HttpHeader and body, abd the second and subsequent data must return just byte array or string data.
I'm coding the follow code, but I'm executing the flush() method in channelContext, but it's not received on the client side.
Our client program can receive it by ChannelFuture.CLOSE i.e. channel is close, but we can still receive only the first data.
What am I missing ? Or is it wrong?

#### Server side

```
    ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
    b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
     .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
     .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
            ch.pipeline().addLast("codec", new HttpServerCodec());
            ch.pipeline().addLast("decode", new HttpRequestDecoder());
            ch.pipeline().addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(Short.MAX_VALUE));
            ch.pipeline().addLast(new ChannelHandler());
            ch.pipeline().addLast("encode", new HttpResponseEncoder());
            //    :

public class ChannelHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<FullHttpRequest> {
    public void channelRead(ChannelContext chlCtx, Object msg) {
        byte[] firstData = new byte[1024];
        byte[] secondData = new byte[1024];
        //    :
        FullHttpResponse response = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, 
        HttpResponseStatus.OK, Unpooled.copiedBuffer(firstData));
        //    :
        chlCtx.write(response);
        chlCtx.flush();
        ChannelFuture lastFuture = chlCtx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(secondData));
        // Client program is no received data.
        //    :
        lastFuture.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
        // Client program is received only first data.
        //    :

}
### Client side ###

    Socket chl = new Socket();
    //    :
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(chl.getInputStream()));
    while (true){
        while ((recv = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(recv);
        }
        if (recv.substring(0,4).equals("LAST"){
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Attach a ChannelFutureListener to the `writeAndFlash` and check what `ChannelFuture.cause()` is

Comment: Thanks Norman.I checked ChannelFuture.cause(). It was io.netty.handler.codec.EncoderException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected message type: UnpooledHeapByteBuf.

Comment: based on the error you want to remove all the handlers from the pipeline before you try to write a ByteBuf.

Comment: Thanks Norman. I tried to remove the Handler just before writingAndFlush method the second data (byte array, not Http format), but although a message was sent, a NullPointerException occurred when writing the third and subsequent data, etc. , Does not seem to work properly. Isn't the implementation method good?

Comment: In the first place, it specifies to use Handlers such as HttpRequestDecoder and HttpResponseEncoder to easily check and set the contents of HttpHeader. If I handle the HttpHeader part as a byte array or String without using these Handlers, will the current problem be solved?